# Storing secure keys on Ubuntu web server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, django, ubuntu-12.04, gunicorn

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 Precise with a DUNG (Django, Unix, Nginx & Gunicorn) environment and my app (as well as various config files) is stored in a python virtual environment inside `/srv`, which the `www-data` user has access to.

The nginx & gunicorn processes are all run as `www-data`.

My web app requires secure credentials which I am storing in an `environment.sh` file. This file contains various exports and is run using `source` before the gunicorn processes execute.

My concern is the location of the `environment.sh` file and it's permissions. Will it be okay storing this file inside the `/srv` folder where the `www-data` has access to it? Or should it be stored and owned by root somewhere else such as `/var/myapp/environment.sh`?

Also, regarding the `www-data` user, if any of my web processes (which are run as `www-data`) are compromised and someone gains access to them, does that mean that the user could potentially read any file on the system, even if they can't write? Including my secure keys?

Comment: +1 for making me laugh.  I've never heard the acronym "DUNG" before.

Answer (score 1):

You can set user and group IDs in gunicorn configuration that will be used by the worker processes. Set the environmental variables in file owned by root and without read permissions (rw-------). This will save your compromised www-data proccess from reading data directly from configuration file, **but compromised www-data proccess can still read variables directly from memory.**

ps. +1 for DUNG :)